# How to resolve local DTDs without System.Xml.Utils.Dll(XmlPreloadedResolver)?

Tags: .net, xml, gac, dtd, resolve

I use an external DTD to validate my xml files. Since the XmlReader seem to look for the DTD only in the folder where the xml file is, I need to somehow tell the reader to look into a specific folder where my dtd's are.

I though of XmlPreloadedResolver to solve this but I cannot find System.Xml.Utils.Dll in the GAC. Isn't this a standard .NET framework  assembly?

EDIT: It seems this DLL relies on silverlight to be installed. Is there another way to use a dtd for validation which is in another folder than the xml file itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Xml.Utils.dll is not part of the standard .NET Framework.  It is included as part of the Silverlight SDK.  If you haven't already installed it, you can do so from here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1ea49236-0de7-41b1-81c8-a126ff39975b&displaylang=en

Once you have it installed, the assembly you want to reference in your project will be under %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Libraries\Client\

This assembly includes the class System.Xml.Resolvers.XmlPreloadedResolver

Answer (score 1):

According [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/hanuk/archive/2008/05/11/silverlight-for-the-enterprises-fundamentals.aspx), `System.Xml.Utils.dll` is *"optional and will be included in the package (XAP) based on the usage"*.

Seems this assembly is Silverlight related; on my machine, I just found it inside `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v?.0\Libraries\Client` directories

Comment: So if I haven't silverlight I must always have my DTD files in the same folder where the xml files are?

Answer (score 0):

.netfx 4.0 includes XmlPreloadedResolver in the System.Xml.dll. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.resolvers.xmlpreloadedresolver.aspx for details.